# Can we pass external url to google cloud vision api to detect image labels?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, google-vision

I have written a below code using AWS lambda function in node js.

```
'use strict';
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const image = 'http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    client
        .labelDetection(image)
        .then(results => {
            console.log(results);
            const labels = results[0].labelAnnotations;
            console.log('Labels:');
            labels.forEach(label => console.log(label));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('ERROR:', err);
        });
};
```

But i am getting error like a "We are not allowed to access the URL on your behalf. Please download the content and pass it in."

could you please help us on this.

Comment: If you want to use the nodeJS client, you have to download the image first, and in the labelDetection function pass the path to the downloaded image ex:  
client.labelDetection(''C:\\Users\\mejia\\Pictures\\picDownloaded.jpg")